# Remove dots from the path in .NET

Tags: .net, path

How can I convert `c:\foo\\..\bar` into `c:\bar`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\foo\\..\\bar"); // path = "C:\\bar"
```

[More Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\foo\..\bar");
```

in C# using the System.IO.Path class?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to preserve relative path's without converting them into absolute path, also I wanted to support both - windows and linux style linefeeds (\ or /) - so I've came up with following formula & test application:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Script
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simplifies path, by removed upper folder references "folder\.." will be converted
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path to simplify</param>
    /// <returns>Related path</returns>
    static String PathSimplify(String path)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String newPath = new Regex(@"[^\\/]+(?<!\.\.)[\\/]\.\.[\\/]").Replace(path, "" );
            if (newPath == path) break;
            path = newPath;
        }
        return path;
    }


    [STAThread]
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify("x/x/../../xx/bbb") == "xx/bbb");
        // Not a valid path reference, don't do anything.
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify(@"C:\X\\..\y") == @"C:\X\\..\y");
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify(@"C:\X\..\yy") == @"C:\yy");
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify(@"C:\X\..\y") == @"C:\y");
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify(@"c:\somefolder\") == @"c:\somefolder\");
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify(@"c:\somefolder\..\otherfolder") == @"c:\otherfolder");
        Debug.Assert(PathSimplify("aaa/bbb") == "aaa/bbb");
    }
}
```

Remove extra upper folder references if any

Comment: As a rule of thumb: With each regex you introduce, you introduce another problem. This rule applies here: `C:\X\\..\y -> ..\y`, `C:\X\Y\Z\\\..\y -> C:\X\\..\y`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. '.' matches for any character, while I've meant actually dot. So dot should be escaped. Fixed into answer above.

But for your case path will not be changes, because there is double slash before dots. "\\..". From my perspective it's not valid path and better to keep it as it was.

Comment: But my examples demonstrate that the paths _are_ changed. And double backslashes are, as far as I know, valid by definition.

Comment: Here's another example for which your code is wrong, without double backslash: `x/x/../../xx -> x/../xx`. Furthermore, you completely ignore `.`.

Comment: You're right, if we have ..\.. we should not try to remove "..\..". This can be achieved using negative lookahead (http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). Will update answer to work for this case as well.

Comment: Previous edit did not. Added now test application, if you find out more problems, I'll be happy to add more test cases.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is `Syetem.IO.Path` as it provides methods to deal with several issues regarding generic paths, even Internet paths.

Answer (score 2):

Try System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\foo..\bar")

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that works with both relative and absolute paths on both Linux + Windows. The solution still relies on `Path.GetFullPath` to do the fix with a small workaround.

It's an extension method so use it like `text.Canonicalize()`

```
/// <summary>
///     Fixes "../.." etc
/// </summary>
public static string Canonicalize(this string path)
{
    if (path.IsAbsolutePath())
        return Path.GetFullPath(path);
    var fakeRoot = Environment.CurrentDirectory; // Gives us a cross platform full path
    var combined = Path.Combine(fakeRoot, path);
    combined = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
    return combined.RelativeTo(fakeRoot);
}
private static bool IsAbsolutePath(this string path)
{
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
    return
        Path.IsPathRooted(path)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
private static string RelativeTo(this string filespec, string folder)
{
    var pathUri = new Uri(filespec);
    // Folders must end in a slash
    if (!folder.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString())) folder += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    var folderUri = new Uri(folder);
    return Uri.UnescapeDataString(folderUri.MakeRelativeUri(pathUri).ToString()
        .Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this implementation works very well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this yourself, you may use this code:

```
var normalizePathRegex = new Regex(@"\[^\]+\..");
var path = @"C:\lorem\..\ipsum"
var result = normalizePathRegex.Replace(unnormalizedPath, x => string.Empty);
```

URLs and UNIX-style paths:

```
var normalizePathRegex = new Regex(@"/[^/]+/..");
var path = @"/lorem/../ipsum"
var result = normalizePathRegex.Replace(unnormalizedPath, x => string.Empty);
```

Note: Remember to use [RegexOptions.Compiled](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27313&seqNum=6) when utilizing this code in a real-world application

Answer (score 0):

Convert to full path and back to a relative path

```cs
public static string MakeRelative(string filePath, string referencePath)
{
    var fileUri = new Uri(filePath);
    var referenceUri = new Uri(referencePath);
    return Uri.UnescapeDataString(referenceUri.MakeRelativeUri(fileUri).ToString()).Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
}

public static string SimplifyRelativePath(string path)
{
    var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    var result = MakeRelative(fullPath, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer, but from the question I suspect you are trying to reinvent the [System.IO.Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method. That should eliminate the need to create paths like the one you are asking about overall.

Comment: Path.Combine does not resolve "..", it simply concatenates two paths using a single path separator (depending on the platform).