# Converting relative paths to absolute paths C#

Tags: c#, string, path, uri

I have a program that trawls html files and finds href tags, takes the string inside (the link), and converts it to the file location.

The problem comes when the href tag uses relative links, eg:

`<a href="../../../images/arrow.gif"/>`

In that case, my program returns:

```
\\server\webroot\folder\foo\bar\mew\..\..\..\images\arrow.gif
```

for example (because it doesn't start with "http", it appends the path of the file it's in to the start).

This, obviously, can be simplified to:

```
\\server\webroot\folder\images\arrow.gif
```

Is there an object that can do this kind of simplification, or do I need to do some string parsing - and if so what's the best way?

Comment: The two answers you have seem to assume a different mode for your app to be running in (i.e. Local file system vs. retrieving files via the web, using URLS.) Please clarify your question to make whichever answer you accept clear. (They both are spot on for their authors assumptions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using ASP.NET here. In this case, I think you simply want the [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28VS.90%29.aspx) function to return the actual physical URI of the file.

```
var absoluteUrl = this.Server.MapPath("../../../images/arrow.gif");
// absoluteUrl = "\\server\webroot\folder\images\arrow.gif"
```

(`this` refers to the current page of course. You can always use `HttpContext.Current.Server` instead, if that's not available for whatever reason.)

**Note:**
If you want to do things manually and you already have a specific string like "\server\webroot\folder\", then the functionality of `System.IO.Path` should do the job I would think:

```
var absoluteUri = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("\\server\webroot\folder\",
    "../../../images/arrow.gif"));
```

Comment: Path.GetFullPath("\\server\webroot\folder\foo\bar\mew\..\..\..\images\arrow.gif") does the job - great, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Uri class to combine them:

```
Uri root = new Uri(@"\\server\webroot\folder\foo\bar\mew\", UriKind.Absolute);
Uri relative = new Uri("../../../images/arrow.gif", UriKind.Relative);

Uri comb = new Uri(root, relative);
```

Answer (score 3):

The Path class provides the method GetFullPath(string path)

For example

```
Path.GetFullPath(@"\\server\webroot\folder\foo\bar\mew\..\..\..\images\arrow.gif")
```

returns

```
@"\\server\webroot\folder\images\arrow.gif"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the obvious candidates:

- `Path`
- `DirectoryInfo`

I bet they have some method to do this. Guess: Create a new `DirectoryInfo` object for your path and then check the properties - probably canonical path in there somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

See answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939289/2338477

It's better because it does not require path to `Uri` remapping, and `GetFullPath` in a turn involves file system operations, and because of this answer will be probably faster than other versions here. (Pure string manipulation)