# FIle path from app.config windows application

Tags: c#

I always have doubt regarding how a path is formed whenever we run a windows app.

I have set a key like this in my app config

```
<add key="LogFilePath" value="..\Log\" />
```

When i run this from my local machine, it provides the path from where the windows app is run.

But when i run the same project from TFS, and when i try to create a file inside the Log folder , instead of the project mapped path it gives an entirely different path.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

save the relative path in config and where you want to use it do it like this

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,configPath);
```

Comment: Hi, this will return the path from where the application is started right? what about Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath))+ path from app.config?

Comment: yes, it will. Don't you want the application startup path?

Comment: Hey, good news i am told to hard code the complete path in app config. Shew.  now that's a headache gone. THanks all

Answer (score 0):

App Settings are very straight forward.

Add your properties to your App.Config app settings, e.g.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="LogFilePath" value="C:\Jaspreet_Files\LoadOrgInPortal.txt" />
</appSettings>
```

and read them, e.g.

```
var sqlConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LogFilePath"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is `..` in the value:

```
<add key="LogFilePath" value="..\Log\" />
```

This seems to be a relative path, try to [get full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970911/net-remove-dots-from-the-path) first before writing and see where it is writing and where it should.